# When destructor is called automatically?

Tags: c++

I'm playing around with `destructor` and `operetor=` and the output was strange to me.

Main functions for both versions:

```
int main()
{
    B b1;
    B b2;
    b2=b1;
    cout<<"---"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

1. The following code work as expected and the output is:

`class B
    {
        public:
            B operator=(B& b1)
            {
                cout<<"operator="<<endl;
                return b1;
            }
            ~B()
            {
                cout<<"destructor"<<endl;
            }
    };`

output:

```
operator=
destructor // Did it print because `b2` got new value so the old value is going to trash?
--
destructor
destructor
```

2. Now the operator= return `B&` instead of `B` and the output is not the same; the destructor is called twice and not three times as before. Why?

`class B
    {
        public:
            B& operator=(B& b1)
            {
                cout<<"operator="<<endl;
                return b1;
            }
            ~B()
            {
                cout<<"destructor"<<endl;
            }
    };`

output:

```
operator=
--
destructor
destructor
```

Comment: because in one case your `operator=` returns a newly created instance (it should not) and in the other case it does not. Isnt it obvious?

Comment: btw the "isnt it obvious" isnt meant as an offense, just trying to understand what you are missing

Comment: Both functions are written incorrectly in the sense that `operator=` should be returning a reference to the current object, not a brand new object, and not a reference to another object.

Comment: do you know what this does exactly does under the hood??:  ***b2=b1;***

Comment: @tobi303 I still dont understand why in the second case the destructor doesn't get called. @PaulMcKenzie Do you mean that I should allocate memory on the heap for every call to `operator=` so I can return his reference? @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ I guess I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: the destructor gets called but only at the end of the scope. In the first case you have one additional instance (the one returned from the operator) that gets deleted already at the end of the line, because you dont keep a reference to it.

Comment: @StavAlfi -- `return *this;`  That is what `operator=` should return.  Returning anything other than that is non-intuitive, runs counter to what the assignment operator should return, and would be a source of bugs that are very hard to find.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks for the tip. The way I implemented it is for self learning the automatic calls for destructor, constructor and copy constructor in cpp. And that was pretty good training.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case you have one additional instance :

```
int main()
{
    B b1;
    B b2;
    b2=b1;               <---- here b2.operator=(b1) returns another B instance 
                               (its a copy of b1)
    cout<<"---"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

that gets destroyed already at the end of the line, because you dont keep a reference to it. You could write:

```
   B b3 = (b2=b1);
```

to keep the instance alive until the end of the scope. In that case you would see the destructor being called after you print `---`.

Also note, that both of your operators are not correct in the sense that the operator should return a reference to `*this` not to some other instance. (Was already mentioned in a comment by PaulMcKenzie, just repeat it here to make sure it doesnt get lost)

Answer (score 0):

The code is working perfectly fine and as expected. In the first case, the destructor is being called after "operator=" because you are returning a local copy of the object of B:

```
B operator=(B& b1)
{
    cout<<"operator="<<endl;
    return b1;
}
```

Note that the statement "return b1" will return a local copy (and not a reference), and it will get destructed as soon as the scope ends. You can test verify this by writing your own copy constructor and put a trace inside that. I did the following:

```
class B
{
    public:
        B operator=(B& b1)
        {
            cout<<"operator="<<endl;
            return b1;
        }
        ~B()
        {
            cout<<"destructor"<<endl;
        }

        B(const B& b1){
            cout << "Copy constructor called" << endl;   
        }

        B(){}
};
```

I got the following output:

```
operator=
Copy constructor called
destructor
---
destructor
destructor
```

However in the second case where the return type of assignment operator overload is B&, the copy constructor will never be called because it will be returning reference to the object it received and not a copy. As a result, destructor will be called only twice for the objects b1 and b2 created in your main() method.
Hope this answers your query.

Comment: "because you are returning a local copy of the object of B:" there is no local copy, otherwise the destructor would be called twice (once for the local and once for the returned instance in main)

Comment: Yes there is, because of the return type in the first case(which should not be ideally). You are explicitly telling the function to return "B" and not "B&", so it calls the copy constructor and returns the instance and not the reference.

Comment: yes, but there is no local copy inside the `operator=`

Comment: Agreed, I should not call it a "local copy" actually.